# Delphi 3 Memory Allocation Problem

Tags: delphi, memory-management, linked-list

I must be missing something rather easy?  I’m trying to create a linked list in a Delphi 3 application.

This is implemented via two classes *ItemList* and *Item*.  The *ItemList* is instantiated at form creation.  It persists for the life of the form.  Each *Item* object is instantiated as needed.  The form has a function called *AddAcc*.  *AddAcc* is called via the on-change event of one of the form's controls.

What happens during this on-change event:

1. *AddAcc* is called
2. *AddAcc* create a new *Item* object
3. *AccAdd* calls *ItemList.AddItem* and passes the *Item* by reference
4. *AddItem* places *Item* object at the tail of the list

I’ve tested *AddItem* and it works well.  My problem is that each time *AddAcc*is called it obtains the same memory location.  I’ve tried different means of creating a new *Item* object.  I’ve used New, GetMem (w/ FillChar), and instantiating a local variable of type Item.  All calls to *AddAcc* results in the same memory location being obtained.

I’ve passed the *Item* object directly (by reference) to *AddItem* and alternatively passed a pointer to the *Item* object.

I thought that a reference (pointer) to an instance of the *Item* object within the linked list would ensure the Item's memory location would be maintained.  It appears, however, that it is being collected once the *AddAcc* class is exited.

```
FUNCTION AddAcc;

Var

     accItem : ptrItem;

BEGIN

    GetMem(accItem, sizeOf(Item));

    FillChar(accItem^, sizeof(Item), 0);

    ItemList.AddItem(accItem^);

End;



Procedure TItemList.AddItem(Var newItem : TAccessoryItem);

begin
   Inc(_count);

   // add first item to the list            
    If (_count = 1) Then 
    begin       

          _fifoHead := @newItem;
          _tail := @newItem;
          newItem.Next   := @_tail;
          newItem.Previous := @_fifoHead;
          exit;

    end;

     _tail^.Next := @newItem;  
     newItem.Previous := _tail^;
     mewItem.Next := @_tail;
     _tail := @newItem;         
end;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please can we have some code. Once we see your code, we'll tell you what's wrong in it.

Comment: Please post the code of the code that calls AddAcc, the AddAcc method itself, the lines of code where you declare the ListItem object, and the lines of code where you initialize it. Basically, declarations, initialization, AddAcc + at least one of the places that call AddAcc (and all the code from the method that calls it, not just the line of code that calls it)

Comment: I can guess that you are passing the address of a local variable containing a pointer.

Comment: @David Definitely sounds like it.

Comment: Could you post the real code, this isn't even Pascal. Functions have return values. Could you include type definitions for `Item` and `ptrItem`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd write a linked list:

```
type
  PItem = ^TItem;
  TItem = record
    Next: PItem;
    Data: Integer;
  end;

procedure Add(var First: PItem; Data: Integer);
var
  NewItem: PItem;
begin
  New(NewItem);
  NewItem.Next := First;
  NewItem.Data := Data;
  First := NewItem;
end;

...

var
  First: PItem;
begin
  First := nil;
  Add(First, 42);
  //etc.
end;
```

When you need to deallocate your list you do this:

```
var
  Item: PItem;
begin
  while Assigned(First) do begin
    Item := First;
    First := Item.Next;
    Dispose(Item);
  end;
end;
```

It is my belief that this is the canonical way of writing linked list type code in Pascal.

I've intentionally written this code for this simplest linked list imaginable. That allows you to focus on the allocation, use of pointers etc. You appear to already know how to maintain the references in your more complex list and so I believe you will have no trouble adapting this style of code to your needs.

Comment: Thanks David this helps. I simplified my code to be more in line with what you provided. In doing this, I moved AddItem and the list head and tail pointers out of ItemList and into the unit containing AddAcc. For some reason this allows the memory for each node in the list to be maintained (not garbage collected).  I will investigate this more fully this evening and comment on my findings...I appreciate the help!

Comment: @mad moe, just to clarify: Delphi doesn't do garbage collection. Your code was bad; you called AddItem incorrectly (with `accItem^`, which is the *content* of accItem) instead of the address of the memory block (`accItem` itself - note the missing dereference operator ^), you incorrectly received it in addItem with `var', which means you can change the *address* as well as the content, and then incorrectly used the address-of (@) operator inside addItem. Delphi isn't C# or VB.NET or Java; it doesn't do garbage collection - you're required to manage it yourself. :-)

Comment: @Ken Thanks. I didn't try to get in too deep into OP's code because I felt it was better to start with a clean slate.

Comment: I agreed with your choice until I hit the 'garbage collection' part of Moe's comment; I wanted to make sure that the actual problem was clear enough to avoid that misconception.